# Need a direct way of implementing Azure spring data cosmos db query implementation for a nested parameter

Tags: spring-boot, azure, search, nested, azure-cosmosdb

Say for example an object in cosmosDb looks like this:-

{
  att1: val1,
   att2: val2,
  att3: {
    att4: val4,
    att5: val5
  }
 att6: val6
}

Is there any way of making azure search with 'att4'?

Answer (score 0):

We can create using query methods via the following syntax, and calling it in your implementation class by passing the `att4` value by which you are trying to retrieve the data"0

```
@Repository
interface myRetrieveMethod extends CosmosRepository<DBObject, String> {

List<DBObject> getAllByAtt3_Att4AndAtt3(String att4Value);

}
```